# App closing on start when trying to debug

Tags: android, xamarin

When I'm trying to start debugging an android app with Visual Studio 2012, the app will be loaded onto the emulator and tries to start. After a second of black screen I'm back at the home screen.

Releasing and running the app, however, runs flawlessly.

When trying to debug with Xamarin Studio, it works. But I want it to work with VS 2012. Anyone any idea what's going wrong?

If I need to add extra info, please tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem a while back when trying to debug my app in Visual Studio 2012.

To solve it you need to do the following:

- Go to you app settings/properties
- Click mono android options
- Uncheck the option: use fast deployment

I don't know why this solves the problem but it does.
Hope this works for you too!

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks! Was just hoping for an other solution, because this makes loading an app to the emulator seriously slow, haha :-).

Comment: I'm glad this works for you. Yeah it's not a great solution, cause indeed the deploying time rises. I recommend debugging on a device anyway since that's much faster.

Comment: Yes, but it was working before, with fast deployment turned on! Anyway, programming in windows + ms tools is just a nightmare... it has always been.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem, i was not able to debug the xamarin android app on my mobile(Xiaomi mi4i).

The possible things you can try are-
step-1- Delete all the instances of app from your mobile, in my case even if i was deleting it from Settings->installed apps->Your app->uninstall. It was present in FileExplorer Download folder. So make sure nowhere you have any instance of application in your mobile.

step-2-Go to the properties of your android application in VS and perform the below things-
Open Androidmanifest →

Required Permission → Enable ACCESSCOARSELOCATION and INTERNET(tick).

Android Options → Supported Architecture → Enable armeabi and armeabi-v7a
Android Options → Packing Tab → Use Fast Deployment(debug mode only) [uncheck]

Hopefully you will be able to debug. Do try this and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

For android studio:-
Go to file > Settings.
Search for instant runs. disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your device architecture in device manager:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsz0F.png)

Then choose your architectures for DEBUG in Android proporties:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBBp6.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

There might be some problems with libraries PATH's.

I recommend you to use Eclipse instead of those, look a [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) easy tutorial.